# Why do we have to use additional construction when iterating variadic template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

Why do we have to use additional construction such as (`non()` - function, `temp[]` - array, or empty`[](...){}` - lambda) when iterating variadic template parameters?

As known, we can iterate a parameter pack with variadic templates in C++ by using some of these ways:

http://ideone.com/GXDPDw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <valarray>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

template<typename ...Args> constexpr inline void non(Args ...) {}

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum1(T val, Args ...args) { non(val += args ...); return val; }   // v1
// why do we need some function non() here?

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum2(T val, Args ...args) { auto tmp = { val += args... }; return val; }   // v2
// why do we need some array tmp[] here?

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum3(T val, Args ...args) { [](...){}((val += args)... ); return val; }   // v3
// why do we need empty lambda [](...){} here?

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum4(T val, Args ...args) { for(auto &i:{ args... }) val += i; return val; }//v4

template<typename ...Args, typename T = common_type_t<Args...>>
inline T sum5(Args ...args) { return std::valarray<T>({ args... }).sum(); }   // v5


template<typename T> constexpr inline T sum6(T val) { return val; }

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
constexpr inline T sum6(T val, Args ...args) { return val + sum6(args...); }  // v6


int main() {    
    cout << sum1(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum2(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum3(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum4(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum5(1, 2, 3) << endl;
    cout << sum6(1, 2, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But why do we need to use:

1. `non(val += args ...);` instead of `val += args...;`
2. `auto tmp = { val += args... };` instead of `val += args...;`
3. `[](...){}((val += args)... );` instead of `val += args...;`

It would be much clearer and easier to use so:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum(T val, Args ...args) { val += args...; return val; }
```

Why is no there in the standard such possibility, or could such a possibility carry any danger?

And will be such possibility in C++17 or later?

Comment: Also, with `if constexpr`, you don't need additional overloads to process a variadic template parameter pack.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb Thank you. Do you mean some thing like this? http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bNWHskOvPU7pieH5  But this is still not supported in GCC 7.0 with c++1z. In which of c++17/... standard it may appear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because parameter packs must be expanded in a context which expects a syntactic list. A normal function scope is not such a context, so you can't just write `val += args...;`.

However, in C++17, we'll get [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), which will allow you to rewrite your code like so:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
inline T sum(T val, Args ...args) { (val += ... += args) ; return val; }
```

This will be expanded to `(((val += arg0)) += arg1) += arg2)` for three arguments.

Another option would be to write it like this:

```
val += (... + args);
```

This expands to `val += ((arg0 + arg1) + arg2)`

---

Fold expressions will also support expanding arbitrary expressions involving parameter packs, like this:

```
(foo(args), ...);
((mymap[args] = 42), ...);
```

This gives you the power to expand expressions with parameter packs at function scope with ease.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I can do this with flag `-std=c++1z` since GCC 6.1: https://godbolt.org/g/CAo0Mp

Comment: You really need to mention `,` based fold-expressions.

Comment: @Yakk Is that better?

Answer (score 4):

TarlanLlama had given an answer.

In C++17, with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold you can rewrite as:

```
template<typename ...Args>
decltype(auto) sum(Args ...args) {
  return (... + args);
}
```

Live demo http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/801be0c57eca8890